# How to achieve parallel processing in MDB

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, weblogic12c

I am sending message from producer to sender and my receiver is receiving message one by one but I need to process some operation after receiving it.

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/testQueue", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"
            ),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName  = "connectionFactoryJndiName",
                              propertyValue = "jms/testQueueFactory"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
                                      propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge")
})
public class JMSMessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JMSMessageConsumer.class);

    public JMSMessageConsumer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        processOperation(message);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
                LOGGER.debug("Error in exception" + e);
            }
}
```

Please suggest call processoperation needs to process parallely for 1000 messages.

Comment: this should be controlled by how many MDB instances are available in the pool (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/PERFM/mdbtuning.htm#i1134848). Processing 1000 messages in parallel does not seem like a good solution, you certainly don't have 1000cpus, but reducing transaction overhead by batching messages sounds more appropriate if possible (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/WLMDB/batching.htm)

Comment: If I receive the message synchronously how to process async in consumer

Comment: You should not process async in the consumer, parallel processing is achieved thanks to the fact that the container should create multiple instances of your JMSMessageConsumer. This can be fine-tuned at the container level (see the links I provided).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to process 100 message and sending 100 messages   from producer but consumer is receiving 0-9 message first and then next 10-19 ,even if there is a sleep between first 10 message and second, it is in sleep state to complete the first 10 process and then it is processing the next. But I need 100 message to come in one shot to process and all 100 messages can be in sleep state.Is it possible to achieve.

Comment: If it's just a perf issue you should definitely look at tuning the various components of your container. It's possible that the container set a batch size of 10 msgs and then the transaction manager is taking time to mark the transaction done or possibly that the producer is not sending fast enough (try to stop consumers on the queue to fill the queue with 10000 messages and then re-activate consumers). If you need batch of 100 messages because of application constraints then you should pack your 100 messages into a single JMS message.

Comment: how to receive 100 message in one go where 10 messages are coming for once cycle. I have tried with consumption - pause and resume but there is no effect. And I can clearly identify that the first 10 message are processed it is picking the next threads. please suggest is there any way to receive all the message to start process parallely